# How to use onload event from Image in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to get some info from an image that i load using new image() with typescript. I try this code:

```
width;
heigth;
init(){
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = "url";

    image.onload((event) => {
    this.width = event.width;
    this.heigth = event.heigth;
    })
}
```

But i get this error:

> void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Event'. Property
>   'bubbles' is missing in type '() => void'

I search examples on how to use this event but i can't find anything.

Answer (score 13):

You are trying to call `onload` rather than assign an event handler. Here is a quick fix for you...

```
image.onload = (event) => {
  // ...
};
```

You will also find that the general `Event` type doesn't have width and height, so you may need to specialise the type for that too.

```
interface SizedEvent {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

function isSizedEvent(e: any): e is SizedEvent {
  return (e && e.width !== undefined && e.height !== undefined);
}  

image.onload = (event) => {
  if (isSizedEvent(event)) {
    // event.width is now available
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

HTMLImageElement worked for me:

```
  image.onload = function (this: HTMLImageElement) {
  const height = this.height;
  const width = this.width;
  console.log('Image size ', [width, height])
};
```

Comment: What a neat solution!

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 14.1, I was also able to simply cast to `HTMLImageElement`...

```js
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = (onLoadResult) => {
    const img = onLoadResult.target as HTMLImageElement;
    // do cool stuff
    }
    image.src = screenShotDataUrl;
```